# Order by inclusion

Tags: order-theory

Given the set $E = \{a,b,c\}$, order the power set of $E$ (all subsets) by inclusion.

I think the order would be $\varnothing$, $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, $\{c\}$, $\{a,b\}$, $\{a,c\}$, $\{b,c\}$, $\{a,b,c\}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: It's not a linear order, so it's not entirely clear what "order" you really mean.

Comment: Is $\{a\}\subseteq\{b\}$? No.

Comment: A partial order would be {},{a},{a,b},{a,c},{a,b,c} ?

Comment: No, as $\{a,b\} \not \subseteq\{a,c\}$. A partial order by inclusion would be $\{\} \subset\{b\} \subset \{a, b\}\subset \{a,b,c\} $ but there are others

Comment: You can't express (without some prior definition) a partial order with a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- You have correctly identified the elements of the power set
- Arrange them in a natural way with one at the top, three in the next row, three in the row below that, and one at the bottom, and then show the order by inclusion with arrows.

Answer (score 0):

It would be partially ordered set, because you can't compare 2 arbitrary elements in the power set, as $\{ a \} \not\subseteq \{ b\}$. Check out the [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram)

Answer (score 0):

Hint 2: 
Not all elements in the powerset of $E$ are comparable by set inclusion, so your diagram will consist of the union of all the linear orders of the subsets of $E$, where $E$ is the maximal element and $\emptyset$ is the minimal element.